# convert char **arr to char*arr[]

Tags: arrays, pointers

I am really confused with the usage of pointers and arrays.
I am trying to pass some value from command line to an array. And I need to used the array for other processing.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<const char *> args {};
    args.insert(args.end(), argv+1, argv + argc);

    const char **arr = args.data();
}
```

This works but is not what I want, the original code is using

```
const char *arr[] = {"some", "vaule", "here"};
```

I want to passing the value to arr instead of assignment inside the code.

I need the array but the code below doesn't work.

```
const char *arr[] = args.data();
```

So I want to keep my array like this because of other processing, how can I do it?
Thank you!

Comment: The args variable should be initialised with a constructor not by {}, that's what my mingw-g++ version says

Comment: It is highly unlikely that you really need the `std::vector` you're trying to construct.  Also, you cannot "pass things to an array". If you want to process your command-line arguments - just do that; they are right there. If you want to iterate over them, you could consider [`gsl::span<char*>`](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-span-T-in-the-CppCoreGuidelines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing various ideas here.

char * argv[] is a pointer to an array of arguments, which themselves (since they are c 'strings') are arrays of characters. Therefore argv is a 2-d array.

Variable assignment like

```
const char *arr[] = args.data();
```

does not work, you can only assign with a static list like {"some", "vaule", "here"}

In order to set the values within arr to the same values as argv, you need to loop through argv and copy the values of the strings into arr.

This can get complicated and since you are writing in c++ you might as well work with vectors.

Where you would do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> arr(argv + 1, argv + argc);
```

In which case you would then have a vector containing the values of the arguments passed in.

Hope that was what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

`char **arr` is practically the same type as `char *argv[]`
You can assign it directly:

```
const char **arr = argv;
```

The compiler might show the warning, but it should compile.